# The type or namespace name 'NUnit' could not be found

Tags: c#, frameworks, selenium

I have a c# code.(which is exported from selenium IDE)

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Selenium;

namespace SeleniumTests
{
[TestFixture]
public class csharp
{
private ISelenium selenium;
private StringBuilder verificationErrors;

[SetUp]
public void SetupTest()
{
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://localhost:1924/");
selenium.Start();
verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
}

[TearDown]
public void TeardownTest()
{
try
{
selenium.Stop(); 
}
catch (Exception)
{
// Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
}
Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
}

[Test]
public void TheCsharpTest()
{
        selenium.Open("/cookie/Default.aspx");
        selenium.Type("id=TextBox1", "ranadheer");
        selenium.Type("id=TextBox2", "SE");
        selenium.Type("id=TextBox3", "hyderabad");
        selenium.Click("id=Button1");
        selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.Click("id=Button2");
        selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000"); 
}
}
}
```

I pasted this code in a console application (visual studio 2008).
After running, I got this errors:

> The type or namespace name 'NUnit' could not be found.
>   The type or namespace name 'TestFixture' could not be found
>   The type or namespace name 'ISelenium' could not be found
>   The type or namespace name 'SetUpAttribute' could not be found

What framework should I add to correct this errors?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems like you have references missing. From official [Selenium docs page](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_installing_dotnet_driver_client.jsp):

> Add references to the following DLLs: nmock.dll, nunit.core.dll,
>   nunit. framework.dll, ThoughtWorks.Selenium.Core.dll,
>   ThoughtWorks.Selenium.IntegrationTests.dll and
>   ThoughtWorks.Selenium.UnitTests.dll

For your current problem, you need to reference at least NUnit.Framework.dll and Selenium dlls.

Please read the docs page for more info.

Answer (score 9):

Right click on references in the solution explorer and click add reference.
You will need to browse for the nunit.framework.dll

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a reference to the NUNIT dll

Comment: The dll is called nunit.framework.dll and can be downloaded from the NUNIT website

Comment: You also need the Selenium dll (ThoughtWorks.Selenium.Core.dll)