# Nunit DLL issue - Namespace can't be found?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I installed NUnit via NuGet.  NUnit shows up in my project references, and there doesn't appear to be a problem.

I created a test class, just to make sure it loaded correctly:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class UnitTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestMethod()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

However, when building, I get:

> "The type or namespace name 'NUnit' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I removed and re-added the appropriate DLL for my project (for .Net 4.0) manually, yet no success - I continue to get the error when building.

Is there a potential issue I'm missing?

There some [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884015/the-type-or-namespace-name-nunit-could-not-be-found), but the answers did not work for my issue.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: why don't you try creating a NUnit test in a new console app and confirm if it's a NUnit issue or your current test project.

Comment: Which version of NUnit? Is the nunit.framework.dll in your packages directory? If you view properties for the nunit.framework reference, does it point to the correct assembly?

Comment: @RobProuse NUnit v3.2.1.0.  I verified that the reference is pointing to the DLL.  Then, I deleted the reference and added it again to make sure.  It's blowing my mind a bit - it shows up in Intellisense and looks integrated in the IDE, but I still get the error!

Comment: @KMC - I made the console app and it worked fine.  Looks like it's an issue in my winforms project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, I had the target framework in the project properties set to ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile."  I changed it to ".Net Framework 4", and the problem is solved.

For those looking for further fixes, see [this solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884015/the-type-or-namespace-name-nunit-could-not-be-found)